# Нужна ли тут запятая: "Керамика 18 века(,) исследована И.Ивановым"?

Tags: пунктуация

Керамика 18 века(,) исследована И.Ивановым.

Comment: Если перейти на традиционное письмо (XVIII в.), то работы и букв станет меньше.

Answer (score 1):

(1) В записи порядковых числительных (кроме дат) используется буквенное наращение (18-й век).

> [Вопрос № 232663](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=20-%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA)
>   Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно 20 век или ХХ век? И можно ли вообще использовать наращения типа 20-й век, 20-го века.
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Для обозначения веков обычно используются римские цифры: XX век. При написании арабскими цифрами наращение нужно: *20-й век, 20-го века*.

(2) Ответ зависит от контекста. Если это подпись под экспонатом, заголовок или тому подобное (вот мол керамика 18-го века, которая была исследована И.Ивановым), то так:

**Керамика 18-го века, исследована И.Ивановым**
А еще лучше так:
**Керамика 18-го века. Исследована И.Ивановым**
Можно также использоавть скобки:
**Керамика 18-го века (исследована И.Ивановым)**

Примечание: в конце заголовка точка не ставится.

А если это предложение, повествующее о том, что керамика 18-го века была исследована И.Ивановым, то так:

**Керамика 18-го века исследована И.Ивановым.**